# Worpress bad request 400 pure Javascript

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I get this following error when I use ajax in pure javascript:

> "POST http://localhost:8888/website/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 400 (Bad Request) line in code: this.xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));

my Contact.js file:

```
var Contact = function(data){
    //setups and others methods
    this.onFormSent = function(data){

        data = {
            action: 'my_action',
            data: data
        };

        if(this.ajaxSendURL !== null){
            this.xhr.open("post", this.ajaxSendURL);
            this.xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            this.xhr.onload = function() {
                if(self.xhr.status === 200){
                    console.log(self.xhr.responseText);
                    var response = JSON.parse(self.xhr.responseText);            
                    self.onSuccessForm(data);
                }       
            };            
            this.xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    };   
};
```

I use a form tag in html after filled my "form" and pressed the submit button it should call 'my_action' in php.

this my function.php:

```
function add_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('Contact', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/Contact.js', array(), 1.0, true);
    wp_localize_script('Contact', 'ajaxurl', admin_url('admin-ajax.php'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts');

/* AJAX */
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action');

function my_action(){
    echo 'msg from server:' + $_POST['data']['name'];
    die();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Updated: replaced by the following code and it works

```
this.onFormSent = function(data){
    data = "action=my_function&name=" + dada.name;
    this.xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Contact.js is a plugin?

Comment: No is my custom js function in "theme_folder/js/Contact.js"

Comment: can you post your contact.js code?

Comment: tm getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined`

Comment: I post my full Contact.js code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this lines in ajax request;

```
    data = {
        action: 'my_action',
        data: youdatadata
    };

    var data = $.param(data);


    http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


    http.send(data);
```

Comment: Do not send JSON to functions.php file

Comment: It works I forget to change data value by encoded string